# Indexing with ragged tensors in tensorflow.js

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to index a batch in tensorflow with a ragged tensor.

```
X = tf.constant([[[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]],
            [[9,8,7], [6,5,4], [3,2,1]]])
```

The first dimension is the batch, the second is the sequence length.
Using gather_nd I can select the individual rows and columns.

```
tf.gather_nd(X, [[[0, 1], [0, 2], [0, 0]], [[1, 0], [1, 1], [1, 2]]])
```

But I have to use a ragged tensor as the input for the selection.
For example.

```
tf.gather_nd(X, [[[0, 1], [0, 2]], [[1, 0], [1, 1], [1, 2]]])
```

This of course does not work.
Is there a way to make the above code work?

Answer (score 2):

You need to explicitly create a `RaggedTensor` object as tensorflow does not recognize them automatically:

```
>>> tf.gather_nd(X, tf.ragged.constant([[[0, 1], [0, 2]], [[1, 0], [1, 1], [1, 2]]], inner_shape=(2,)))
<tf.RaggedTensor [[[4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]], [[9, 8, 7], [6, 5, 4], [3, 2, 1]]]>
```

However, if your ultimate goal is to filter out specific batches, `tf.boolean_mask` ([API)](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/boolean_mask) might be more straight-forward for this.

Comment: You cannot build the ragged tensor like that, you should rather use `tf.ragged.constant([[[0, 1], [0, 2]], [[1, 0], [1, 1], [1, 2]]], inner_shape=(2,))`. And the result should also be a ragged tensor like `[[[4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]], [[9, 8, 7], [6, 5, 4], [3, 2, 1]]]`.

Comment: @jdehesa You're absolutely right, thanks, I've updated it.